# Register XML schema using dbms_xmlschema in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, xml

I have a xsd file located at C:\temp\test.xsd

I need to register this schema to create a XMLType table for Object Relational XML Storage.

How do I register the schema for relational storage?

I do not seem to find any example on internet for registering the schema for relational storage.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A simple example can be found here: http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2007/06/24/oracle-11g-xmltype-storage-options/ Search the site for more info or ask/search on the Oracle XMLDB forum or have a look in the Oracle XMLDB Developers Guide: https://community.oracle.com/community/database/high_availability/xml_db HTH